# How to slide and rotate UIImageView animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to make an animation that moves an `UIImageView` to another location on the screen of the device and simultaneously rotates the view.

I tried using `UIView` methods like `transitionWithView` and `animateWithDuration` and they work most of the time but not every time.

Randomly the animation seems to run so that the animation does not start from the current position but instead the `UIImageView` slides to its position from somewhere outside the screen. The ending point is correct and if I set the view transform without animation the end result is correct. So, it just looks like every now and then the starting transform for the animation is messed up.

I'm trying to work around this glitch by resetting the view transform before the animation with `CGAffineTransformIdentity` but even then I'm randomly seeing the view slide in from outside the screen. I tested this also on device and the same issue exists.

Here is the simplified code for the case. I'm reseting the transform to a fixed point on screen. Then I create a transform with a little slide up and rotation and in the animation I set this transform to the image view. The wait flag with run loop is there to make sure the execution does not continue from this call before the animation is finished.

```
-(void) foldAnimation:(int)player {
    // reset view transform
    UIImageView *leftCard = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:6];
    leftCard.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 120.0, 408.0);

    // slide and rotate
    float ySlide = -80.0 + arc4random_uniform(5);
    CGAffineTransform transform1 =  CGAffineTransformTranslate(leftCard.transform, 0.0, ySlide);
    transform1 = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform1, M_PI/180*(arc4random_uniform(7)-2));

    waitFlag = YES;
    [UIView transitionWithView:leftCard
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                animations:^{
                    leftCard.transform = transform1;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    waitFlag = NO;
                }];

    NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    while (waitFlag && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
}
```

Comment: try changing the options argument in transitionWithView:  there to  (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState )    This may be happening when an existing animation is underway..

Comment: Adding UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState did not fix the issue but it more clearly points out that the animation is beginning from wrong state. I added a run loop and a short wait after the lines that reset the transform. And now I can see that the reset happens on UI but after that the animation begins every time from some different state i.e. the reset lines in my code are useless.

Comment: I tried also reseting by [leftCard.layer removeAllAnimations] but it has no effect either. The direction from which the image slides in to the screen suggests that the x,y coordinates of the image view are swapped. The reason may be that earlier in the app the image has been flipped with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft. If I remove the rotation from the transform I'm not seeing the glitch so I changed my design just to have the translation without rotation.